# What about --include-directory option for MikTeX's lualatex.exe?

Tags: miktex, winedt

I tried to run MikTeX `lualatex` from within `WinEdt` after a long break and got an error message saying the `--include-directory` is an unknown option. And indeed, running `lualatex --help` reveals that such an option is absent in the list of regular options. `WinEdt` automatically adds `--include-directory` when it calls any latex engine. Usually I use `xelatex` and it still runs successfully with this option.

> Is it an error in a recent update of MikTeX? Or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

WinEdt compile scripts used to rely on MiKTeX command line options like `--include-directory` when it came to using auxiliary files redirection.

Starting with version 10.0, IIRC, WinEdt doesn't do that anymore, for the reasons you are seeing now.

MiKTeX's `lualatex.exe` used to "tolerate" that command line option (although it has never worked), but newer versions doesn't anymore.

**This option will be available for `lualatex.exe` in MiKTeX 2.9.6300 which will be released in April, 2017. See this feature request of mine for that: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/feature-requests/334/**

In the meantime, you have two options:

1. Upgrade to the latest WinEdt 10.2
2. Open a local copy of the file `LuaLaTeX.edt` and substitute its contents with

   ```
   // -*- ASCII:EDT -*-
   // TeX: LuaLaTeX ...

     Requires(20110812); // Requires this build of WinEdt to work properly

     PushTagsandRegisters;
     Assign('ExitCode-OK','0'); // OK Exit Code
     LetReg(9,'LuaLaTeX'); // Execution Modes Compiler
     LetReg(8,'log');      // Log File (or empty)
     LetReg(7,'pdf');      // Output Format
     LetReg(6,'%O');       // Startup Folder

     // Display a Dialog for Extra Switches:
     IfStr("%$('%!9-GUI');","1","=",>
       !|GetString("Switches: ","%!9 Switches","%$('%!9--Switches');");>
         IfOK(!`Assign('%!9--Switches','%!?');`,!`PopTagsandRegisters;Exit;`);|,>
       !|Release('%!9--Switches');|);
     // Non-Stop Mode?
     IfStr("%$('%!9-No_Interaction');","1",!"=",>
       !"LetReg(3,'--interaction=nonstopmode');",!"LetReg(3,'--interaction=errorstopmode');");
     // C Style Errors?
     IfStr("%$('%!9-C-style-errors');","1",!"=",!"LetReg(3,'%!3 --file-line-error');");
     // TeX Sync?
     Assign('Sync');
     IfStr('%0',!'--src',!'<>',!'JMP("no_Sync");');
     IfStr('%$("PDF-SyncTeX");',!'1',!'<>',!'JMP("no_Sync");');
     IfStr('%$("PDF-Sync");',!'',!'=',!'JMP("no_Sync");');
     Assign('Sync','%$("PDF-Sync");');
   :no_Sync:: ==========================================================
     // Build the Command Line ...
     LetReg(5, "%$('%!9-Executable'); %$('%!9-Switches'); %!3 %$('Sync'); %$('%!9--Switches'); %$('%!9-Parameters');");

     // Use Execution Modes to determine the flow of execution...
     Exe('%b\Exec\ExeCompiler.edt');
     PopTagsandRegisters;

   End;
   ```

   which is the contents of the file you would have in WinEdt 10.2.